# BlackBerry - how two merge two images

Tags: graphics, blackberry, drawing

I want to merge two images in blackberry. one image is a big image and other image is a small one. position of small image will be define by developer. what are the possible ways?

Comment: If it wasnt so urgent i could answer you, but id have to do a little bit of research, so i probably wont be able to answer you in time. sorry.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Graphics class to draw multiple Bitmaps onto it in different offsets. Look into the [Graphic.drawBitmap](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html#drawBitmap(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap,%20int,%20int)) function. We use something like:

```
graphics.drawBitmap(x1, y1, icon.getWidth(), icon.getHeight(), icon, 0, 0);
```

Where the graphics object is the one passed by the paint method we override and icon is the large image. Than determine the x y position for the smaller image and use the same method on the graphics object:

```
graphics.drawBitmap(x2, y2, mark.getWidth(), mark.getHeight(), mark, 0, 0);
```

Where mark is the smaller image.

Hope this helps  :)