# Nine patch library for BlackBerry SDK

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I was searching a way to use nine-patch images in order to handle multiple screen size but I did not find. Do you know if it exists such library ?

Comment: why you don't write it yourself, it shouldn't be too complex, generate images on runtime. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501269/blackberry-how-two-merge-two-images

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will have a look at it.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [BlackBerry-NinePatch](https://github.com/mobiata/BlackBerry-NinePatch) package and the [related blog post](http://www.mobiata.com/blog/2011/10/25/building-the-flighttrack-ui-on-blackberry).